# How to interpolate pandas dataframe such that a column is sampled in given interval?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some dataframe:

```
time    data
1       1
2       2
3.5     3
4.22    5
9.1     3
10.2    4
```

time is assured to be ascending.

I want a dataframe in which the time column is interpolated in a given range `(start, stop, step)`, and the data column(s) is sampled accordingly, by some interpolation method(s).

I would like a possibility for extrapolation, meaning I want `start` or `stop` to be able to be lower than the minimal time value or larger than the maximal.

How can I do this?

I could accept numpy solutions, but prefer to stay only within pandas if possible.

Comment: ```df = df.interpolate()```

Comment: @GökhanGerdan this doesn't accept a `start, stop, step`. not that i saw anyway. There are non `NaNs`. I want to generate new values.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom interpolation function. Something along these lines:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
def interpolator(g: pd.Series):
    x = [...]
    y = [...]
    interpolated_array = interp1d(x, y, bounds_error=False, fill_value=0)(g)
    return interpolated_array

grouped = df.groupby('column_a')
df['column_intepolated'] = grouped['column_b'].transform(interpolator)
```

If you want to give it a try, and struggle to adapt to your data, please do comment, and I'll post it here.